# What are the best sources of XP after the Elite Four in BW2?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

In *Pokémon Black 2* and *Pokémon White 2*, what are the best sources of XP that are available after defeating the Elite Four?

Defeating the Elite Four again is the traditional post-game XP source, and Route 15 has some high-level Pokémon, but where else is good?

Comment: If you're playing White 2 or have the White Forest unlocked in Black 2, you can go to the White Treehollow and fight the Breeders there; they all use Chansey and/or Blissey in their teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black Tower and White Treehollow. As Krazer said in the comment, there are trainers who use Chansey and Blissey in the White Treehollow, so there's more experience there.

Comment: Yes, the trainers in the tower have pokemon that range from 50s to 80, great for training well up to level 100.